# Stopping an asynchronous Actor?

Tags: scala

Is it possible to stop an asynchronous Actor in scala (i.e. uses react / not receive)?

I had a search and this answers it for synchronous Actor?

[Scala Actors: Is there a built-in way to stop/ interrupt an actor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117334/scala-actors-is-there-a-built-in-way-to-stop-interrupt-an-actor)

Note: there are also stop mechanisms for Akka actors. But this question is for the Scala actor.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're writing a new application, you really should go with Akka.

Comment: They are indeed deprecated, you can find information on migration here: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/actors-migration-guide.html